# Visual Studio Code - R Language Server

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I have recently started using Visual Studio Code and I successfully installed it on my PC. I followed all the descriptions of the article by Kun Ren:

https://renkun.me/2019/12/11/writing-r-in-vscode-a-fresh-start/

However, when I start VS Code I get the following error message:

R Language Server (5016) started
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U"
Execution halted
R Language Server (5016) exited with exit code 1

My settings.json looks like this:

```
{
    "r.bracketedPaste": true,
    "r.rterm.windows": "C:\\Users\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts\\radian.exe",
    "r.rpath.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.0.5\\bin\\x64\\R.exe",
    "r.lsp.debug": true,
    "r.lsp.diagnostics": true,
    "r.sessionWatcher": true,
    "r.rterm.option": [
        "--no-save",
        "--no-restore",
        "--r-binary=C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.0.5\\bin\\x64\\R.exe"
    ],
}
```

Comment: I think if you change those double backslashes \\ to forward slashes / it should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Find your `.Rprofile` file. There should be a line in there that reads:

```
options(langserver_library = '<path to>\languageserver-library')
```

Change the backslashes to forward slashes, then restart VS Code and R.

Comment: Hello Weihuang,
thank you very much for your answer! VS Code is now runnung with the R language server. I used too many different sources for installing it so that is why it did not work out at the first attempt. After uninstalling VS Code and only following the instructions by Kun Ren the installation finally worked out. Very glad to have VS Code with R language server as alternative to RStudio Client. Still a lot of coding to learn for me :-)

Thanx again for helping me out and sorry for my late reply!

Regards,
Henry