# Why do I get this error when using R in vscode?

Tags: r

I am trying to use R in vscode but I keep getting this error:

```
r language server started 
vscode undefined is not recognised
```

Can someone help me fix it?

Full error output [here](https://gyazo.com/bf471531f0c2faf05f9750aae219ef1a)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide to format your question according to community guidlines.

Comment: Are you able to reinstall vscode (and anything else required to run R in vscode), and try again. The reason I suggest that first is because I see [this issue](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/716) in which there was a similar problem which since appears to have been fixed.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67268001/5783745) may be related too.